# HTML template not opening on the outlook 7, why?

Tags: css, html

The below code is not working on the outlook 7. please help me how to resolve this issue.

I have added only header section of my code, let me know any other you want.

help me on this

Thanks

I don't know what to add the content below (leave the below information)

(HTML stands for Hyper Text Markup Language
HTML describes the structure of Web pages using markup
HTML elements are the building blocks of HTML pages
HTML elements are represented by tags
HTML tags label pieces of content such as "heading", "paragraph", "table", and so on
Browsers do not display the HTML tags, but use them to render the content of the page)

```html
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /><meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" /><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" /><title>Newsletter</title><style type="text/css">
        /* Resets */
        .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; background-color: #ebebeb;}
        .ExternalClass {width: 100%; background-color: #ebebeb;}
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height:100%;}
        a[x-apple-data-detectors]{
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration:none !important;
            font-size:inherit !important;
            font-family:inherit !important;
            font-weight:inherit !important;
            line-height:inherit !important;
        }        
        body {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;}
        body {margin:0; padding:0;}
        .yshortcuts a {border-bottom: none !important;}
        .rnb-del-min-width{ min-width: 0 !important; }

        /* Add new outlook css start */
        .templateContainer{
            max-width:590px !important;
            width:auto !important;
        }
        /* Add new outlook css end */

        /* Image width by default for 3 columns */
        img[class="rnb-col-3-img"] {
        max-width:170px;
        }

        /* Image width by default for 2 columns */
        img[class="rnb-col-2-img"] {
        max-width:264px;
        }

        /* Image width by default for 2 columns aside small size */
        img[class="rnb-col-2-img-side-xs"] {
        max-width:180px;
        }

        /* Image width by default for 2 columns aside big size */
        img[class="rnb-col-2-img-side-xl"] {
        max-width:350px;
        }

        /* Image width by default for 1 column */
        img[class="rnb-col-1-img"] {
        max-width:550px;
        }

        /* Image width by default for header */
        img[class="rnb-header-img"] {
        max-width:590px;
        }

        /* Ckeditor line-height spacing */
        .rnb-force-col p, ul, ol{margin:0px!important;}
        .rnb-del-min-width p, ul, ol{margin:0px!important;}

        /* tmpl-2 preview */
        .rnb-tmpl-width{ width:100%!important;}

        /* tmpl-11 preview */
        .rnb-social-width{padding-right:15px!important;}

        /* tmpl-11 preview */
        .rnb-social-align{float:right!important;}

        @media only screen and (min-width:590px){
        /* mac fix width */
        .templateContainer{width:590px !important;}
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 360px){
        /* yahoo app fix width "tmpl-2 tmpl-10 tmpl-13" in android devices */
        .rnb-yahoo-width{ width:360px!important;}
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        td[class="rnb-container-padding"] {
        padding-left: 10px !important;
        padding-right: 10px !important;
        }

        /* force container nav to (horizontal) blocks */
        td[class="rnb-force-nav"] {
        display: block;
        }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {

        /* center the address &amp; social icons */
        .rnb-text-center {text-align:center !important;}

        /* force container columns to (horizontal) blocks */
        td[class~="rnb-force-col"] {
        display: block;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        width:100%;
        }

        table[class~="rnb-container"] {
         width: 100% !important;
        }

        table[class="rnb-btn-col-content"] {
        width: 100% !important;
        }
        table[class="rnb-col-3"] {
        /* unset table align="left/right" */
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;

        /* change left/right padding and margins to top/bottom ones */
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;*/
        }

        table[class="rnb-last-col-3"] {
        /* unset table align="left/right" */
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        }

        table[class="rnb-col-2"] {
        /* unset table align="left/right" */
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;

        /* change left/right padding and margins to top/bottom ones */
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        /*border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;*/
        }

        table[class="rnb-col-2-noborder-onright"] {
        /* unset table align="left/right" */
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;

        /* change left/right padding and margins to top/bottom ones */
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        table[class="rnb-col-2-noborder-onleft"] {
        /* unset table align="left/right" */
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;

        /* change left/right padding and margins to top/bottom ones */
        margin-top: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        }

        table[class="rnb-last-col-2"] {
        /* unset table align="left/right" */
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        }

        table[class="rnb-col-1"] {
        /* unset table align="left/right" */
        float: none !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        }

        img[class="rnb-col-3-img"] {
        /**max-width:none !important;**/
        width:100% !important;
        }

        img[class="rnb-col-2-img"] {
        /**max-width:none !important;**/
        width:100% !important;
        }

        img[class="rnb-col-2-img-side-xs"] {
        /**max-width:none !important;**/
        width:100% !important;
        }

        img[class="rnb-col-2-img-side-xl"] {
        /**max-width:none !important;**/
        width:100% !important;
        }

        img[class="rnb-col-1-img"] {
        /**max-width:none !important;**/
        width:100% !important;
        }

        img[class="rnb-header-img"] {
        /**max-width:none !important;**/
        width:100% !important;
        margin:0 auto;
        }

        img[class="rnb-logo-img"] {
        /**max-width:none !important;**/
        width:100% !important;
        }

        td[class="rnb-mbl-float-none"] {
        float:inherit !important;
        }

        .img-block-center{text-align:center!important;}

        .logo-img-center
        {
            float:inherit!important;
        }

        /* tmpl-11 preview */
        .rnb-social-align{margin:0 auto!important; float:inherit!important;}

        /* tmpl-11 preview */
        .rnb-social-center{display:inline-block;}

    }</style><!--[if gte mso 11]><style type="text/css">table{border-spacing: 0; }table td {border-collapse: separate;}</style><![endif]--><!--[if !mso]><!--><style type="text/css">table{border-spacing: 0;} table td {border-collapse: collapse;}</style> <!--<![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 15]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG/><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:AllowPNG/><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml><![endif]--></head>
```

Comment: seems like you forgot to post your code.

Comment: sorry, i have posted my code as answer

Comment: i will post complete code, so that i can get answer

Comment: Please remove your answer and edit the question adding the code to it.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: where is your html ? its just styles

Comment: sorry, i have tried to post the entire code but it didn't allowed me to do. that is the reason, i have posted only styles(i have a doubt on styles, that also in last line).

Answer (score 0):

you havent post any html but try this:

```
<a href="mailto:manish@simplygraphix.com?subject=Feedback for webdevelopersnotes.com&body=The Tips and Tricks section is great">Send me an email</a>
```

Comment: I have posted above, please check